# For each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ either no $x$ with $f(x) = y$ or two such values of $x$. Show that $f$ is discontinuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.

> Let $f$ be a function defined in $[0, 1]$ such that for each real number $y$ either there is no value of $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = y$ or there are exactly two such values of $x$. Prove that
>
> a) $f$ must be discontinuous on $[0, 1]$.
>
> b) $f$ has an infinite number of discontinuities in $[0, 1]$.

Long back I had tried to solve the problem. I reasoned for a) as follows:

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and let $m, M$ be its minimum and maximum values on $[0, 1]$. Clearly if $m = M$ then $f$ is constant and clearly for every $x \in [0, 1]$ we have $f(x) = m = M$ which contradicts given property of $f$. So we must have $m < M$. Clearly there are now four distinct points $a, b, c, d$ in $[0, 1]$ such that $f(a) = f(b) = m, f(c) = f(d) = M$. By checking possible linear orderings of $a, b, c, d$ I could find a find a value of $y \in (m, M)$ for which there exist more than 2 values of $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. However this approach looks very clumsy and I suspect much simpler and easier proof is possible.

Part b) seemed bit complex and my only guess was that probably $f$ was discontinuous on each subinterval of $[0, 1]$ but I could not prove this claim (may be the claim is wrong!). Perhaps there is a simpler solution to this part of the problem.

Apostol's also asks to provide an example of such a function.

Any hints on the overall problem will be appreciated.

---

**Update**: After looking at Marc's answer, I think I have found a way to show that there are infinitely many discontinuities. Earlier the solution was a part of the question itself but it made the question look quite lengthy hence I moved it to a separate answer.

Comment: The infinitely many discontinuities follows immediately once we have shown a). And a) is easy, the only nuisance is writing out the details.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Can you give any feedback for the approach I used in part a)?

Comment: The idea is close to the one I used. In your post, there is no detail about how to find the values that are taken on more than twice. If you carry out the detail, you will have a proof as clumsy as mine!

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I wonder how you see the infinitely many discontinuities immediately. In my answer that case is obtained from a somewhat subtle parity consideration, which does not seem present in the continuous case. I don't see how your considerations for the continuous case carry over to the finitely discontinuous case; for instance the maximum might be attained once continuously and once discontinuously.

Comment: it looks as if I may have seen something that wasn't there (a quick path from the easy a).

Answer (score 11):

First observe that a function $f$ that is continuous on an open interval  $I$ and has no local extrema in $I$ (points where the value is the minimum or maximum of the values in a neighbourhood) must be strictly monotonic (increasing or decreasing) on $I$. To show this, assume for $a<b<c$ that either both $f(b)\leq f(a)$ and $f(b)\leq f(c)$ or both $f(b)\geq f(a)$ and $f(b)\geq f(c)$; then some minimum respectively maximum of $f$ on the compact set $[a,c]$ will lie in its interior and therefore be a local extremum, contradicting the hypothesis.

Next, a continuous function on an open interval $I$ that never takes the same value more than twice (and in particular cannot be locally constant anywhere) cannot have two local extrema of the same nature (both minimum or both maximum). Again an easy contradiction is obtained after assuming for instance that $a<c$ are local minima with $f(a)\leq f(c)$ say, $b\in(a,c)$ a maximum of $f$ on $[a,c]$, and $d>c$ a point of $I$ with $f(c)<f(d)<f(b)$; then $f$ also takes the value $f(d)$ on each of $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$.

This already allows proving point a) by deriving contradictions for each of the cases of a continuous function having zero, one or two local extrema in $(0,1)$.

Now consider the case of a function$~f$ with finitely many discontinuities. By cutting the interval at each discontinuity and at each of the local extrema of$~f$ (which are finite in number by the above arguments), we partition $[0,1]$ into $n$ open intervals $I_i$ on each of which $f$ is continuous and strictly monotonic, and $n+1$ isolated points. The image of each $I_i$ is an open interval; we can define a multigraph on the set of endpoints of all $f(I_i)$, with an edge from $\inf(f(I_i))$ to $\sup(f(I_i))$ for each$~i$. Because of the property required for$~f$, local consideration of the closure $J$ of $f(\bigcup_iI_i)$ near any vertex shows that only four kinds of vertices are possible: if the vertex is on the boundary of$~J$ then it either has two ingoing or two outgoing edges, otherwise (the vertex is in the interior of$~J$) it either has two ingoing and two outgoing edges, or one incoming and one outgoing edge. The final case is the only one in which the vertex is in (the interior of) $f(I_i)$ for some$~i$, and it will be so for exactly one$~i$; let $V_1$ be the set of these vertices.

Our contradiction will come from a parity condition, namely that $|V_1|\equiv n\pmod2$. This congruence is obtained by counting the endpoints of the $n$ edges of our multigraph modulo$~2$: the vertices of $V_1$ contibute $1$ to this count and all other vertices contribute $0$. Now the values of $f$ on the $n+1$ isolated points must be such that each vertex of $V_1$ is used exactly once, and any other value used (which must be outside $f(\bigcup_iI_i)$) must be so exactly twice. But parity shows this is not possible.

Comment: I must say I am deeply impressed by the graph-theoretic / combinatorial argument to prove the infinity of discontinuities. This is so unlike calculus/real-analysis proofs(which I have seen so far).+1

Comment: I have tried to convert your argument into the language of calculus and analysis and put that as an update in my post. The basic idea is to split $[0, 1]$ into an odd number of open sub-intervals such that $f$ is continuous and monotone in each of these. Please let me know if my version is OK.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I've read your argument, and I don't think it is quite correct: since the result comes from parity, you cannot afford to simply drop without any trace one of the $x_i$ in case $f(x_i)=f(x_j)$. But maybe one can prove along the lines you indicate. Call a point in the image of $f$ singular unless the inverse image by $f$ of a sufficiently small neighbourhood is the union of two intervals on each of which $f$ is continuous and monotonic. Then (modulo proof) the set of $x$ with $f(x)$ singular is finite and even, and contains all discontinuities and local extrema. Now conclude.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I had dropped one of the $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ only to let it appear as one of $y_{i}$. To elaborate perhaps some of $x_{i}$ are paired so that their number is even and for remaining ones we find the pairing from $y$'s. The idea is that the number of points $x$'s and $y$'s taken together must be even.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Suppose that we have three discontinuities $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ with $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$. Then we find a $y$ such that $f(x_{3}) = f(y)$ and consider set $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, y\}$ and number of points in this set is even.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I have now modified my argument slightly which should take care of the point you raised.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I still don't quite understand your revised version (cannot see how the same number of $x$'s and $y$'s come about in all cases, and what they are). I think the essential point is to distinguish regular and singular values in the _image_ of $f$ first (this requires no choice whatsoever), and then take inverse images. The contradiction comes from the requirement that the inverse image of the singular values is an even number of (isolated) points, while the inverse image of the regular values is the disjoint union of an even number of open intervals.

Comment: And note that a value can be singular without being the image of a discontinuous point (instead it would be the image of a local extremum and of an endpoint of the interval, or the image of another local extremum of opposite nature). I don't get the reason why "the extrema come in pairs".

Comment: After your latest comments I will think further and will update my answer. Maybe there are still some serious gaps in my logic.

Comment: I have updated my post to straighten out counting arguments and I don't think I am missing any points of discontinuity of extrema and the points which they are paired up with.

Comment: It's very nice answer!!

Answer (score 7):

a) Suppose to the contrary that $f$ is continuous. The maximum value $M$ of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is taken on twice, say at $a$ and $b$, where $a\lt b$.

Suppose that $0\lt a\lt b\lt 1$.  Let $m_1$ be the minimum of $f$ in the interval $(a,b)$, and let $c$ be a point in $(a,b)$ where this minimum is attained.  Let $\epsilon=\min(M-f(0), M-m_1, M-f(1))$.

Consider the number $M-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is an $x_1$ in the interval $(0, a)$, and $x_2$ in the interval $(a,c)$, and $x_3$ in the interval $(c,b)$, and an $x_4$ in the interval $(c,1)$ such that $f(x_i)=M-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. This contradicts our assumption that each value is taken on exactly twice.

A very similar argument can be given if $a=0$ and $b\ne 0$, and also if $a\ne 0$ and $b=1$.  The only difference is that we find values that are taken on at least $3$ times.

Suppose now that $a=0$ and $b=1$.  Then  there are $a,b$ with $0\lt a\lt b\lt 1$ at which $f$ attains a minimum. Now we can use essentially the same method as the one we used when  the maximum is reached at points strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I essentially had the same approach and I must thank you for writing the solution in detail. But I am not yet able to make transition to the infinite discontinuities.

Comment: I think you mean "..and an $x_4$ in the interval $(b,1)$" right

Answer (score 7):

This is a solution to part b) of the question and it is in part inspired by the answer from Marc and discussion with him.

---

**Pairing Discontinuities and Endpoints**: Let us assume on the contrary that there are a finite number of discontinuities $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$. Then by the given property of $f$ (that it takes every value twice) we have numbers $y_{i}$  such that $f(x_{i}) = f(y_{i})$. Let us consider set $$A = \{x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n}, y_{1}, y_{2}, \cdots, y_{n}\}$$ On the face of it there seem to be $2n$ elements in this set $A$. However it may happen that we have $f(x_{i}) = f(x_{j})$. In this case we will have $y_{i} = x_{j}, y_{j} = x_{i}$. Thus there will be $2$ duplicates which will be ignored during counting members in $A$. Effectively this means that $A$ has even number of distinct points. It may happen that one or both of the points $0, 1$ are not in $A$. Let's find points $a, b$ such that $f(a) = f(0)$, $f(b) = f(1)$. It can also happen that $a, b$ turn out to be $0, 1$. Add these points $0, 1, a, b$ also in $A$. Now the set $$A = \{0, 1, a, b, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}, y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n}\}$$ has an **even** number of **distinct** points. Removing them from $[0, 1]$ will partition the interval into **odd** number of open subintervals such that $f$ is *continuous* in each of these open subintervals.

**Pairing Local Extrema**: Next by the nature of the function $f$ (every value taken twice) number of local extrema in each of these open intervals is finite (each open sub-interval of continuity of $f$ can have "one local maximum", or "one local mimimum" or "one local maximum and one local minimum"). Let these points of local extrema be $c_{1}, c_{2}, \ldots c_{k}$. Note that none of these points are in set $A$ and for every $x \in A$ we have a $y \in A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Hence the corresponding points $d_{i}$ with $f(c_{i}) = f(d_{i})$ are also not in $A$. Note that the $d_{i}$ may or may not be local extrema of $f$. And like in the case of $x$'s and $y$'s if we take $c$'s and $d's$ together to form set $$B = \{c_{1}, c_{2}, \ldots, c_{k}, d_{1}, d_{2}, \ldots, d_{k}\}$$ the set $B$ will have **even** number of **distinct** elements. Let $S = A \cup B$ and since $A \cap B = \emptyset$, it follows that the set $S$ will also have **even** number of **distinct** points. And to emphasize $S$ has another property like $A$ or $B$ namely that for each $x \in S$ we have a $y \in S$ with $f(x) = f(y)$.

**Final Step**: Removing points of $S$ from interval $[0, 1]$ will generate an **odd** number of disjoint open sub-intervals and $f$ will be *continuous and monotone* in each of these open subintervals. Clearly the image of $f$ on such open subintervals will also be an open interval (say $I_{r}$). Because $f$ takes every value twice each of the images $I_{r}$ will be paired with another $I_{s}$ (i.e. $I_{r} = I_{s}$). But since the number of such intervals is odd, the pairing is not possible and we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to prove the part b), but I find a example of such function.

Let $A=\{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n} : n\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}\}\cup \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $A=A_1\cup A_2$ be a partition of $A$. Enumerate $A_1=\{b_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ and $A_2=\{c_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Define $f$ such that

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 n+1 & \text{if $x=b_n$ or $x=c_n$}\\
 x(1-x) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: there is only one value $x = 1/2$ for which $f(x) = 1/4$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh... I correct this error.

Comment: Yeah it now looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a somewhat different proof of this statement:

$a)$ $Claim:$  $\forall$${\epsilon}>0$ ${\exists}$ ${ {\delta}>0}$ with $\mid x-y \mid < \delta$ $\implies$ $\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid < \epsilon$ with $x,y  \in [0,1]$, $i.e$ $f$ is $continuous$ on $[0,1]$.

$Now,$ Choose a $neighborhood$ around $x$: $[x-{\delta_1}, x+{\delta_1}]$ with $\delta_1<\delta$, such that $f(x) = f(x+{\delta_1})$. And Clearly $f(x) {\ne} f(x-{\delta_1})$ as a particular value of $f$ can only take place $Twice$ on $[0,1].$

Now, with $y=x+\delta_1,$ we have $\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid = 0$ $(\because f(x) = f(x+{\delta_1}) )$, So any value greater than $0$ can be assigned to $\epsilon$.

But for $y=x-\delta_1$;   $\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid > 0.$  Now, $choosing:$ $\epsilon < \mid f(x)-f(x-\delta_1) \mid$ leads to a $contradiction$, $i.e.$ $\exists$ at least one $\epsilon>0$ such that even with $\mid x-y \mid < \delta$, we get $\mid f(x)-f(x-\delta_1) \mid > \epsilon$

$\therefore$ $f$ is $discontinuous$ on $[0,1].$

$b)$ If There is no $x$ such that $f(x)=y$, it is trivial that $f$  has $infinite$ discontinuities on $[0,1]$, and if there are exactly two such values of y, with $f(x_1)=y=f(x_2)$ $with$ $ x_1 \ne x_2$ we can define the neighborhood around $x_1$: $[x_1-\delta_1, x_1+\delta_1]$ with $x_2 = x_1 + \delta_1$. And prove for the discontinuity at $x_1$. And this way, for all such values with two values of $f$ on $[0,1]$ we can prove for discontinuity.

Comment: Your argument does not work as you have chosen $\delta$ first and then chosen $\epsilon $ on the basis of that. One is supposed to chose $\epsilon $ first.

Comment: I have chosen $\epsilon$ first, and then according to the $\delta$, I have chosen a neighborhood, such that, the distance of the endpoints from center of the neighborhood, is lesser than our $\delta$.

Comment: It does not look like that. Clearly the choice of $\delta$ such that $f(x) =f(x+\delta) $ is not dependent on $\epsilon $. At a later stage you clearly choose $\epsilon$ in terms of $\delta $ to get a contradiction. You need to review clearly what you have written. Replacing $\delta$ with $\delta_1$ does not help

Comment: No I didn't replace $\delta$ with $\delta_1$. I separately chose $\delta$ and $\delta_1$ with the property $\delta_1<\delta$ to make sure, $\mid x-y \mid < \delta$ as, $\mid x-y \mid = \delta_1$, when $y=x+\delta_1$.
And one can choose this $\delta_1$ $\forall \delta>0$ from the choice of each $\epsilon>0$ and, this still holds true, as we can still find a neighborhood: $[x-\delta_1, x+\delta_1]$ with $f(x)=f(x+\delta_1)$.

Comment: According to the problem: Either $\nexists$ $x$ $for$ $f(x)=y$ or, $for$ $x,y \in [0,1]$ with $x\ne y$, we get, $f(x)=f(y)$

And all we need to do, is to find such pairs of $f(x)$ $and$ $f(y)$ where $\mid x-y \mid < \delta$, and go for proof of continuity. And still the contradiction will occur if we consider the neighborhood around $x$: $[x+(x-y),x-(x-y)]$ or $[x-\delta_1, x+\delta_1]$ ($\because$ $y = x+\delta_1$)(taking: $\mid x-y \mid = \delta_1$), and check continuity at the other end of the interval, $i.e.$ $for$ $x-\delta_1$ $here.$

Comment: The two values of $x$ for which $f$ takes same value may themselves be far apart anywhere in $[0,1]$ and not necessarily lie $\delta_1$ apart. I don't know why you are assuming these values to lie in the manner written in your answer.

Comment: The property of $f$ specified in question holds on interval $[0,1]$ and not necessarily on every sub-interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108739/discussion-between-pritam-sarkar-and-paramanand-singh).

Answer (score 0):

This answer supplements @Marc van Leeuwen's answer for anyone who does not understand the last two paragraphs in his answer (based on the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539395/a-two-to-one-real-function-must-have-infinitely-many-points-of-discontinuity)).

Suppose $f$ has finitely many discontinuities. Let $S$ be set
\begin{equation*}
    S= \{0, 1\}\cup\{x\in [0, 1]: x\text{ is a discontinuity or local extremum}\}.
\end{equation*}
By the observations in @Marc van Leeuwen's answer, $S$ is a finite set. Let $T = f^{-1}(f(S))$; this is again a finite set (since each element in $f(S)$ has exactly $2$ elements in its preimage). Then $U = [0, 1]-T$ is the union of an odd number of open intervals (since $|T|$ is even) and the restriction of $f$ to each of these intervals is continuous and monotonic. Therefore, the image of each of intervals is also an open interval (the image of an open interval $I$ is $(\inf f(I), \sup f(I))$). Let $U = \bigcup_{i\in J}I_{i}$ and let $i_{0}\in J$. Using the property of the function, each point in $f(I_{i_{0}})$ must be in the image of exactly one other component interval in $U$. In other words, $f(I_{i_{0}}) = \bigcup_{j\in K} (f(I_{j})\cap f(I_{i_{0}}))$ for some $K\subseteq J-\{i_{0}\}$ and the terms in the union are pairwise disjoint open intervals. However, an interval cannot be the disjoint union of more than one interval, so in fact $K = \{j_{0}\}$ is a singleton and $f(I_{i_0})\subseteq f(I_{j_{0}})$. Applying the same argument to $f(I_{j_{0}})$ we get $f(I_{i_{0}}) = f(I_{j_{0}})$. This shows that we can pair the intervals that have the same image. However, we have reached a contradiction since the number of intervals is odd.

**Example:** let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ be any sequence in $(0, 1)$ and consider the function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow [0, 1)$ defined by $f(1) = x_{1}$, $f(x_{n}) = x_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $f(x) = x$ for all other $x$. Then $f$ is a bijection from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1)$. Let $g: [0, 1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = g(x+1/2) = x$ for each $x\in[0, 1/2)$. Then $g\circ f$ is a function with the desired property.