# Is this just asking for the Uniqueness of Limits? If not, how can you do this?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose real function $f$ is continuous at every point.  Prove that $f(x)=c$ cannot have two solutions for every value of $c$.

I think you can prove this by contradiction assuming there are two solutions, $c_1$ and $c_2$.  But something tells me its different from limits.

Comment: The question is asking you to prove that $f^{-1}(c)$ cannot have cardinality $2$ for all real numbers $c$, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Nothing to do with uniqueness of limits :)

Comment: In other words i'm being asked to prove that inverse f of c has a unique solution, right?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have to prove this equation cannot have **exactly** 2 solutions. otherwise, it's easy to find a contradiction. (for example, $x\sin x$)

Comment: see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/677085/72031 The current question is a duplicate but written in form of contrapositive of the the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you meant that `f` cannot have **exactly** 2 solution for `f(x)=c`.

Let's assume there are, so exist $x_1 <x_2$ so $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$. According to the intermediate value theorem, `f` does not alter sign in $(-\infty,x_1)$, in $(x_1,x_2)$, and in $(x_2,\infty)$. Since `f` is bounded in $[x_1,x_2]$, but is onto $\mathbb{R}$, it's clear that $f((-\infty,x_1))=\mathbb{R}^-$ and $f((x_2,\infty))=\mathbb{R}^+$ (or the opposite), so $f((-\infty,x_1)\cup(x_2,\infty))=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.
`f` has a value $c\neq 0$ in $[x_1,x_2]$, (say, in $x_0={x_1+x_2\over 2}$), and according to the intermediate value theorem, the equation $f(x)={c\over 2}$ has one solution in $(x_1,x_0)$, a second solution in $(x_0,x_2)$, and (as said before), a **third**, in $(-\infty,x_1)\cup(x_2,\infty)$.