# If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ then $\exists c\in\mathbb R: f(x)=c$ has only one solution

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

[image]I have to prove that there is no continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation $f(x)=c$ has exactly two solutions.

My attempt:

We have that since $f$ is continuous we can define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in the reals such that $\{x_n\} \to x$ then $\{f(x_n)\} \to f(x)=c$.
Now consider a sequence $\{y_n\}$ in the reals too, such that $\{y_n\} \to x$ then $\{f(y_n)\} \to f(x)$ but because of the uniqness of the limit the result follows.

Am I right? thank you

**I think for the second question What happens then between u and v ? the function is constant isn't otherwise we repeat the value of f(α)=f(β)=e three times and we are not allowed to do this, am I right @Herbert Quain**

Comment: You just wrote the uniqueness of the limit and the continuity of the function.

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677085/for-each-y-in-mathbbr-either-no-x-with-fx-y-or-two-such-values-of

Comment: You don't say what $x$ and $c$ are.

Comment: Ok let me check it I'll go to sleep an tomorrow I'll tell if I'm still stuck right

Comment: Isn't this the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Maybe you should also take an example into account where there are two solutions of $f(x)=x$ for a lot of x, like $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f(x)=c$ has two solutions iff $c>0$, exactly one solution iff $c=0$ and no solution if $c>0$. However, your argument has nothing to do with the claim. As ahorn suggests, I would also try to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: Ok then I should do what is in the page of Paramanand isn't?

Comment: I'll check it in the morning and if I get stuck I will let you know because I have to deliver this homework at Monday and I want to have a good grade then can you help me tomorrow an with the others questions I have post please :) thanks a lot

Comment: You will only be able to get good grades if you understand the problems. However, your first post shows that you do not yet understand the question properly. I think you should first start to understand the statement considering some examples (e.g. as presented above). Then you schould check the Intermediate Value Theorem and also check the proof methods you learned so far (e.g. reductio ad absurdum).

Comment: I just wrote a semi-detailed answer, sketching the arguments but also hiding some others. Try to complete it and to do it by yourself afterwise.

Comment: You should change the title, which is completely different from the actual question. Actually, the statement in the title is false.

Comment: What @rosebud said. For example the function $f(x)=x\sin x$ is continuous, and for each real $c$ the equation $f(x)=c$ has lots of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I wrote the solution but I omitted some key points : try to find them by yourself tomorrow. If you understand the preceding arguments you should not be blocked, otherwise ask for help. 
When you have a problem about continuous functions and solutions of equations $f(t) = c$, you should immediately think about the intermediate value theorem : the proof to come only consists in working with this theorem.

Let's suppose that $f$ is continuous and such that $f(x) = c$ has exactly two solutions. Choose $c$ and suppose $f(x) = f(y)=c$, with $x < y$.

$f$ being continuous between $x$ and $y$, she attains her maximum on this interval at a point $v$.

1) Suppose $x<v<y$ and write $f(v) = M$.Then, $M>c$ (why ?) and there is another point $v$ such that $f(u) = M$. Suppose $u$ is not in $]x,y[$, say $u<x<v<y$.

Consider a real $e$ such that $c <e <M$.Then, if $f$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem, there is at least one solution of $f(t)=e$ in the following intervals :  $]u,x[$,$]x,v[$,$]v,x[$. This is wrong by hypothesis.

So we must have  $x<u<v<y$. Let's sum up the thing using once again the intermediate value theorem : there is one point $\alpha$ in $]x,u[$ such that $f(\alpha) = e$. There is also a point $\beta$ in $]v,y[$ such that $f(\beta) = e$. What happens then between $u$ and $v$ ? 
Conclusion : case 1) is impossible.

2) Therefore we must have $x=v$ or $y=v$, say $x=v$. Then, for every $z \in [x,y]$, $f(z) \leq c$ (why ?). But $f$ being continuous on the interval $[x,y]$, she also attains her minimum at a point $v'$ with $f(v')=m$. We can't have $m=c$ (why ?), so we must have $c>m$. Now apply 1) to the function $-f$ (why is it possible ?).

Both cases are impossible : the situation is absurd.

Comment: Just some advice for you to have good grades : do things by yourself. Read the proof I wrote, re-read it, try to complete it in your head, then shut down your computer and write it all by yourself. Be carefull about all the possible cases (equalities, inequalities, etc.)

Comment: I think for the second question What happens then between u and v ? the function is constant isn't otherwise we repeat the value of $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=e$ three times and we are not allowed to do this, am I right @Herbert Quain

Comment: You're right . Have you tried to do it yourself ?

Comment: Yes :) I have tried to sketch the problem like the photo above an can I ask you other things if I need it ?

Comment: Yes, feel free to ask before I go to bed. (fact : your night fits my day, we might be diametrally opposed on Earth).

Comment: jajaja ok then something else with my argument above I am saying that the 1rst case is imposible isnt :)?

Comment: Yeah, the first case leads to a contradiction. Try to highlight this in your answer.

Comment: Ok ill do it but when do you go to bed because here are 2 pm i dont know in your country ? :)

Comment: It's 8pm in Paris :)

Comment: good then i will go on an i promest to ask you before you go to bed :)

Comment: Then, for every z∈[x,y], f(z)≤c (why ?). It is because x=v tell us that f must be decreasing since f(x)=M and M is the maximum of the interval isn't :)?

Comment: Then, for every z∈[x,y], f(z)≤c (why ?). It isa contradiction because x=v tell us that f must be decreasing since f(x)=M and M is the maximum of the interval  but xwe are assuming x<y isn't :)?

Comment: Well, if $x=v$, then $f(x) = c = M$ is the maximum of $f$ over $[x,y]$, so we have $f(z)\leq M=c$. We assumed in the beginning that $x<y$.

Comment: We can't have m=c since c=M is the maximum of f over [x,y]

Comment: And apliying 1) to -f is only apliying 1) to the reflexion of f and since 1) is a contradiction then apliying 1) to -f is a contradiction too :) and we are done am i right?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: yesssssss then m this problem is done thank you a lot :) herbert quain and I can say it like that isn't or I have to say it more formaly ?

Comment: thanks. Good luck for your studies !

Comment: Thanks Im sure that with your help and our comments Ill get a 10 :) in my homework

Answer (score 3):

We will aim to contradiction. Let $c_0$ be the value of $f(0)$. Then there is another value $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)=c_0$. If $c_0$ is taken exactly two times, then on the interval $(0,x_0)$ value $c_0$ is never taken, so by intermediate value theorem we have that on this interval the values of the function are either always less than $c_0$ or greater than it. Assume the former. Let $c_{min}$ be local minimum of $f$ on $[0,x_0]$, and let $x_{min}$ attan this value. From continuity we can deduce that on $(0,x_{min})$ the function is strictly decreasing, and on $(x_{min},x_0)$ it's increasing, because otherwise some value would be taken more than twice. But from assumption there is another value of $x$ for which $f(x)=x_{min}$, necessarilly outside the interval. Suppose that this $x$ is greater than $x_0$. Then on interval $(x_0,x)$ function takes all values between $c_0$ and $c_min$, which are also taken on intervals $(0,x_{min})$ and $(x_{min},x_0)$, so these values are taken thrice, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

(1) if $f$ has a local maximum (or minimum) the 2-point fiber condition implies this must be a global maximum (minimum). but then $f$ is not surjective as required.

(2) otherwise, since $f$ cannot be constant on an interval, it must be strictly monotonic, hence a bijection. in contradiction to the two-point fiber condition.

i hope this encapsulates our intuition in a straightforward way. the challenge, for this approach, is to find the most elegant and lucid way of applying the intermediate-value theorem to establish (1)