# $f$ cannot be continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a function defined $[0,1]$ with the following property: For every real number $y$, either there is no $x$ in $[0,1]$ for which $f(x)=y$ or there are exactly two values of $x$ in $[0,1]$ for which $f(x)=y$ .

**EDIT:**  Prove that there are infinite discontinuities in this interval

I found a possible solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677085/for-each-y-in-mathbbr-either-no-x-with-fx-y-or-two-such-values-of) but I am not able to comprehend the answer on the page as probably it uses high concepts of graph theory.

Could anybody please give a simpler solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to with 'simultaneously possible'. It may help to note that $f(0),f(1) < M$ by the definition of $M$, so you shouldn't get $M - \epsilon/2 > M$ ever.

Comment: @ArpitKansal I have already mentioned in the question that the problem is related to one you have mentioned