# A two-to-one real function must have infinitely many points of discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ attains each value twice then  prove that it has  infinitely many points of discontinuity.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous except at finitely many points and that every point of $\mathbb{R}$ has exactly two preimages under $f$.  First, note that if $f$ is continuous on an interval $(a,b)$, then it is monotone in a neighborhood of all but at most two points of $(a,b)$.  For if $f$ changed direction at three points $c<d<e$ with (WLOG) $f(c)<f(e)<f(d)$, then it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ takes the value $f(e)+\epsilon$ at least $3$ times, for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Now let $S$ consist of all the points of $\mathbb{R}$ where either $f$ is discontinuous or $f$ changes direction.  By the remark above, $S$ is a finite set.  Let $T=f^{-1}(f(S))$; this is again a finite set.  Furthermore, $f$ is a locally monotone 2-to-1 continuous map from $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus T$ to $V=\mathbb{R}\setminus f(T)$.  Note that $U$ is a disjoint union of $|T|+1$ open intervals, while $V$ is a disjoint union of $|f(T)|+1=|T|/2+1$ open intervals.  By connectedness, each of the intervals that make up $U$ must map into a single one of the intervals that make up $V$.  By pigeonhole, one of the intervals that makes up $V$ has only one interval in its preimage.  But then each point in that interval can only have one preimage under $f$, which is a contradiction.