# No continuous function with $f(x)=y$ having exactly $2k$ roots, $\forall y$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, roots

> Prove that there is no continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, $\forall y \in \operatorname{Im}f$, the equation $f(x)=y$ has exactly $2k$ solutions, where $k$ is a fixed natural number.

I tried to use the continuity and MVT in order to get a contradiction, but I couldn't get too much out of it... Also, I tried to imagine how the graph of such a function would look like, but I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: You probably should try to prove it for $k =1$ and $k = 0$. This should give you a broader picture. (check what you can say about local minima/ maxima)

Comment: The case $k=1$ is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677085/for-each-y-in-mathbbr-either-no-x-with-fx-y-or-two-such-values-of, the given argument can easily be generalized to arbitrary $k$.

Comment: @AndrewC I don't understand this statement. Take the function $x^2-1$, for example, which satisfies the conditions. But it has exactly two roots. What exactly do you mean, or do I miss something?

Comment: It does not satisfy the conditions. For $-1 \in \operatorname{Im}f$, the equation $f(x)=-1=x^2-1$ has only one solution: $x=0.$

Answer (score 0):

For $k = 0$ the statement is obvious.

for $k =  1$. Take $x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ we know that their exists a $c \in [x_1,x_2]$ such that c is a local extrema. What do you know of $f$ at the left side of $c$ and the right side?

Comment: The fact that any value right between $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and that extrema must be taken by $f$ exactly once on the left side of $c$ and exactly once at the right side of $c$?

Comment: Well then $f(x) = f(c)$ would have have 3 solutions. The point would be that their could not be another $x$ such that $f(x) = c$. it is quite clear ones you draw it.