# showing that a continuous function attains each of its values(or each real number in general) exactly 3 times.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

The question and its answer is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But I am wondering how I can prove that the function $f$ attains each real number exactly 3 times, could anyone show me how can I do this?

I also did not understand the proof given in the last paragraph, could anyone explain it for me please?

Comment: . See here =https://math.stackexchange.com/q/735842/377379

Comment: @RAM_3R  I have looked at it before posting my question ..... it does not contain the answer to my question.

Comment: There is a typo: It should be $g_1(x)=2-x$ for $1\leq x\leq 2$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter why it is a typo?

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677085/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  is the given example above contains a typo?

Comment: Yes there is a typo as the given $g_1$ is discontinuous at $x=1$

Comment: Is there any other Typos?

Comment: Draw the graph of this function to see  why it takes each value exactly thrice.